# Re-enable right click blank document

Tags: nautilus, templates

I used to have the option of right clicking in nautilus and adding a New Blank Document. It is gone.  I tried creating one and placing it in a templates folder (which I had to create because it was missing) but to no avail.  Any solutions?

Output of `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Comment: Please run this `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and paste the output.

Comment: # 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file does not look right. Change the

```
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
```

line to

```
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
```